# Inserting value into test box with Javascript

Tags: javascript, insert, greasemonkey

I'm using Greasemonkey to insert a value into a text box, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work. I right click the text box in Firefox and inspect the element. It shows "input**#ExtensionExtnum**.field_for_edit"

```
document.getElementsByName("ExtensionExtnum").item(0).value = "test";
document.forms[0].submit();
```

and I get back:

```
/*
Exception: document.getElementsByName("ExtensionExtnum").item(0) is null
@Scratchpad:8
*/
```

I've gotten this sort of code to work on other websites, for inputting usernames and passwords automatically. I don't understand why it won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = document.getElementsByName("ExtensionExtnum");
if(items.length > 0)
    items[0].value = "test";
```

Comment: I tried this out. I no longer get the 
    Exception: document.getElementsByName("ExtensionExtnum").item(0) is null
error, but it still doesn't populate the field. I wonder if it's just something screwy on the backend of the website.

Comment: 1. See with inspect element if the element with name 'ExtensionExtnum' is rendered in html;
2. If element is rendered, then you are not calling this method right time. For example when your code executes dom is not fully ready, put your code inside `DOMContentLoaded` event handler

Comment: But I am running this within GreaseMonkey - That is to say, I have the page fully loaded and click "Execute", so it should be running after everything is already loaded. I'm fairly new to Javascript, so please excuse my ignorance :)

Comment: @user2607110, what do you mean you "click 'Execute'"?  That's not how Greasemonkey scripts work.  Where is this execute button?

Answer (score 0):

In `input#ExtensionExtnum.field_for_edit`, `ExtensionExtnum` is the element ID, not its name. Thus you must use:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("ExtensionExtnum");
if ( elem !== null) elem.value = "test";
```

If you want to set the value of all the elements of class `field_for_edit`, use:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("field_for_edit");
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
{
  elem[i].value = "test";
}
```

Comment: I tried this out. I no longer get the 
    Exception: document.getElementsByName("ExtensionExtnum").item(0) is null
error, but it still doesn't populate the field. I wonder if it's just something screwy on the backend of the website.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is such an element first

```
    if(document.getElementById("ExtensionExtnum") != undefined)
    {
        document.getElementById("ExtensionExtnum").value = "test";
    }
```

Comment: I tried this out. I no longer get the Exception: document.getElementsByName("ExtensionExtnum").item(0) is null error, but it still doesn't populate the field. I wonder if it's just something screwy on the backend of the website.